# How to integrate OpenID into GlassFish?

Tags: java, authentication, openid, glassfish, jsr196

I want to integrate OpenID as an authentication mechanism into GlassFish 3.1 (preview). The [Development Guide](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7695/gizel?a=view) says that [JSR 196](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=196) could be used to implement custom authentication mechanisms like OpenID.

Is there already an OpenID authenticator for GlassFish conforming to JSR 196? Or is there a tutorial how to write one (somewhere in the blogosphere)?

Comment: Now, this is a good question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For another implementation based on the less experimental [OpenID4Java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) (at least I think so, the OpenID extension is still in alpha and is clearly less widely used than OpenID4Java), see [OpenID ServerAuthModule (JSR-196) with OpenID4Java](http://www-02.imixs.com/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/openid_serverauthmodule_jsr_196_with) that the same author posted last week.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OpenID](https://opensso.dev.java.net/public/extensions/openid/) extension of the [OpenSSO](https://opensso.dev.java.net) project. Here's a blog about it (note, it exist of 3 parts): [part I](http://www-02.imixs.com/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/openid_for_jee_applications_part), [part II](http://www-02.imixs.com/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/openid_for_jee_applications_part1), [part III](http://www-02.imixs.com/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/openid_for_jee_applications_part2).

**Update**: the links in the blog itself were broken (unnecessarily hardcoded with port 8081), so I added the three correct links.

Answer (score 0):

There's an even simpler way of doing it - by using the **[Authentic Roast.](http://code.google.com/p/authenticroast/)** library. I wrote my own OpenID authenticator, plugged into glassfish 3 and it works great!